# Linux shell script with sftp transfer documents, but through the proxy server out

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

Linux shell script with `sftp` transfer documents, but through the proxy server out. How to write it?

```
lftp -u ${USER},${PASSWD} -p ${PORT} sftp://${IP}
```

Comment: See here which options you have: https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/sshproxy.html But it might be impossible, if you have a clever proxy.

Comment: More info please: what is the proxy machine? (SSH/SOCKS). Also, try very hard to not put your password on the command line.